Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Reason', table 'dbo.History'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails
I am modifying a stored procedure to track who made changes.
The modifications are going into the field @summary varchar(max).
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spVndr_UpdateRecord]
(   @nVID       Int = Null, 
    @sVendorName    Char(50) = Null, 
    @nVendorType    Int = Null, 
    @sAltName   Char(50) = Null, 
    @sTaxIDSSN  Char(20) = Null, 
    @sAddress   Char(30) = Null, 
    @sAddress2  Char(30) = Null, 
    @sCity      Char(20) = Null, 
    @sSt        Char(2) = Null, 
    @sZip       Char(10) = Null, 
    @sAreaCode  Char(10) = Null, 
    @sPhoneNum  Char(10) = Null, 
    @sExt       Char(3) = Null, 
    @sEmail     Char(50) = Null, 
    @sFax       Char(15) = Null, 
    @sOldID     Char(20) = Null, 
    @sLicenseNum    Char(20) = Null, 
    @sMedicareID    Char(20) = Null, 
    @sOtherID   Char(20) = Null, 
    @sMisc1     Char(20) = Null, 
    @sMisc2     Char(20) = Null, 
    @sMisc3     Char(20) = Null, 
    @sMisc4     Char(20) = Null, 
    @sWebPage   Char(50) = Null,
    @sComments  Char(255) = Null,
    @sEntryID   INT = Null,
    @sUserLogin varchar(100) = ''
) AS
DECLARE @VenTyp AS varchar(20), @oVendorName varchar(50), @oTaxIDSSN varchar(50),
    @oAddress varchar(50), @oCity varchar(50), @oSt varchar(50), @oZip varchar(50),
    @oAreaCode varchar(50), @oPhoneNum varchar(50), @oEmail varchar(50),
    @oLicenseNum varchar(50), @oMedicareID varchar(50), @oWebPage varchar(50);

SELECT @VenTyp = VendorType
FROM dbo.VendorType
WHERE idVendorType = @nVendorType   

UPDATE 
    dbo.Vendor
SET
    @oVendorName=RTRIM(ISNULL(VendorName, ' ')),
    VendorName = RTRIM(@sVendorName),
    VenTyp = @VenTyp,
    idVendorType = @nVendorType,
    AltName = RTRIM(@sAltName),
    @oTaxIDSSN=RTRIM(ISNULL(TaxIDSSN, ' ')),
    TaxIDSSN = RTRIM(@sTaxIDSSN),
    @oAddress=RTRIM(ISNULL(Address, ' ')),
    Address = RTRIM(@sAddress),
    Address2 = RTRIM(@sAddress2),
    @oCity=RTRIM(ISNULL(City, ' ')),
    City = RTRIM(@sCity),
    @oSt=RTRIM(ISNULL(St, ' ')),
    St = @sSt,
    @oZip=RTRIM(ISNULL(Zip, ' ')),
    Zip = @sZip,
    @oAreaCode=RTRIM(ISNULL(AreaCode, ' ')),
    AreaCode = @sAreaCode,
    @oPhoneNum=RTRIM(ISNULL(PhoneNum, ' ')),
    PhoneNum = @sPhoneNum,
    Ext = @sExt,
    @oEmail=RTRIM(ISNULL(Email, ' ')),
    Email = RTRIM(@sEmail),
    Fax = @sFax, 
    OldID = RTRIM(@sOldID),
    @oLicenseNum=RTRIM(ISNULL(LicenceNum, ' ')),
    LicenceNum = RTRIM(@sLicenseNum),
    @oMedicareID=RTRIM(ISNULL(MedicareID, ' ')),
    MedicareID = RTRIM(@sMedicareID),
    OtherID = RTRIM(@sOtherID),
    Misc1 = RTRIM(@sMisc1),
    Misc2 = RTRIM(@sMisc2),
    Misc3 = RTRIM(@sMisc3),
    Misc4 = RTRIM(@sMisc4),
    @oWebPage=RTRIM(ISNULL(WebPage, ' ')),
    WebPage = RTRIM(@sWebPage),
    Comments = RTRIM(@sComments),
    EntryID = CAST(@sEntryID AS CHAR(3))
WHERE idVendor = @nVID

DECLARE @summary varchar(max) = 
    'spVndr_UpdateRecord: ' +
    'Vendor(idVendor=[' + LTRIM(ISNULL(@nVID, ' ')) + ']) ' + 
    CASE WHEN @oVendorName<>@sVendorName
        THEN 'VendorName: (old: [' + @oVendorName + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sVendorName, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oTaxIDSSN<>@sTaxIDSSN
        THEN 'TaxIDSSN: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oTaxIDSSN) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sTaxIDSSN, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oAddress<>@sAddress
        THEN 'Address: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oAddress) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sAddress, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oCity<>@sCity
        THEN 'City: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oCity) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sCity, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oSt<>@sSt
        THEN 'State: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oSt) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sSt, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oZip<>@sZip
        THEN 'Zip: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oZip) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sZip, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oAreaCode<>@sAreaCode
        THEN 'AreaCode: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oAreaCode) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sAreaCode, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oPhoneNum<>@sPhoneNum
        THEN 'PhoneNum: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oPhoneNum) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sPhoneNum, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oEmail<>@sEmail
        THEN 'Email: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oEmail) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sEmail, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oLicenseNum<>@sLicenseNum
        THEN 'LicenseNum: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oLicenseNum) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sLicenseNum, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oMedicareID<>@sMedicareID
        THEN 'MedicareID: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oMedicareID) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sMedicareID, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    CASE WHEN @oWebPage<>@sWebPage
        THEN 'WebPage: (old: [' + RTRIM(@oWebPage) + ']; new: [' + RTRIM(ISNULL(@sWebPage, ' ')) + ']); ' END +
    ' ';

-- Log event
INSERT INTO dbo.[History]
(
    [UserID],
    [Time],
    [Reason]
)
VALUES
(
    @sUserLogin,
    GETDATE(),
    @summary
)

It is long. I apologize, but the issue comes with the @summary value.
I am testing with various null values being passed in. When I build @summary, I convert all values to string.
Somewhere, what I wrote inserts a NULL value that causes the whole string to be null.
I keep getting this error, and I can't see where it is coming from:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Reason', table 'dbo.History'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

I know if I try to append a NULL value to a string, it turns the whole string to NULL, but it looks like I covered every possible scenario.
Thanks in advance.

We don't have an environment to enable us to debug it... unless you can provide a DBFiddle, you're going to be much faster just debugging it yourself. Just use classic debugging techniques, comment out enough bits until it works, the slowly add them back until you hit the error. Problem found, then fix it.

Or take every variable remove nulls using isnull before your insert.

You don't have any ELSE in your CASE expressions so they will all be NULL if not met. Use CONCAT instead of + to convert NULL to empty string or add an ELSE '' to all of them

Also why are you using CHAR instead of VARCHAR and needing to RTRIM everything?  Email addresses aren't fixed length 50 characters

Didn't you ask pretty much exactly same question a while ago?

@siggemannen - I did. That one was how to convert my NULL values to strings. This one used that answer and still produced nulls. It turns out the CASE statement needs an ELSE clause or it inserts a NULL. I didn't see that anywhere in the CASE documentation. Maybe I missed it.

Your main issue is that your CASE expressions have no ELSE so will evaluate to NULL if not true.
So unless all of them are true the final @summary variable will be NULL as concatenating NULL to anything with the + operator yields NULL by default.
There are a number of other simplifications you can make to your approach too.
e.g. Below shows a pattern for two columns - you will need to extend it for the rest.
UPDATE dbo.Vendor
SET    VendorName = RTRIM(@sVendorName),
       TaxIDSSN = RTRIM(@sTaxIDSSN)
OUTPUT @sUserLogin,
       GETDATE(),
       CAST('spVndr_UpdateRecord: ' AS VARCHAR(MAX))
       + CONCAT('Vendor(idVendor=[', @nVID, ']) ')
       + CASE
           WHEN deleted.VendorName = inserted.VendorName OR (deleted.VendorName IS NULL AND inserted.VendorName IS NULL) THEN ''
           ELSE CONCAT('VendorName: (old: [', deleted.VendorName, ']; new: [', inserted.VendorName, ']); ')
         END
       + CASE
           WHEN deleted.TaxIDSSN = inserted.TaxIDSSN OR (deleted.TaxIDSSN IS NULL AND inserted.TaxIDSSN IS NULL) THEN ''
           ELSE CONCAT('TaxIDSSN: (old: [', deleted.TaxIDSSN, ']; new: [', inserted.TaxIDSSN, ']); ')
         END AS summary
INTO dbo.[History]( [UserID], [Time], [Reason])
WHERE  idVendor = @nVID 


It dispenses with the assigning the before values to scalar variables and uses the OUTPUT clause instead to get these values and inserts the result directly into History.
If you are on SQL Server 2022 you should use deleted.VendorName IS DISTINCT FROM inserted.VendorName etc. and invert the CASE expressions for a simpler null safe equality check.
The individual CASE expressions are using CONCAT for their sub elements which will automatically convert NULL to empty string so no need for ISNULL there (unless you intend to use it to distinguish NULL from empty string).
It makes sure the first item concatenated with + is of type varchar(max) to avoid possible truncation if the length exceeds 8,000 bytes.
As the values are RTRIM-med on their way into the table I removed it in the string concatenation, you will need to add this back in if you find you do still need it (e.g. if the column datatypes in the table are also CHAR rather than VARCHAR for some misguided reason)


That's some good SQL writing. I like how you included an OUTPUT section to the UPDATE. That is something I've never tried before. I wonder if it can be used with my INSERT statements, too. Hmmm... And yes, these tables are very old. The code has fixes for the Y2K bug, and over half of the tables use CHAR rather than VARCHAR.

This is related to handling of NULL values. Remember: NULL does NOT mean empty/missing. It means you don't know. This causes two common points of confusion, both of which are likely in play here:

First, the part we know: when you concatenate a NULL string with another string, the result is NOT the other string, as if NULL were just an empty string. Because NULL means you don't know the value, you also don't know the result of the concatenation operation... and therefore the concatenation result is also NULL.
The result can be also surprising when using NULL as one operand of a conditional expression. Specifically, no matter what the operator (=,<>, >, <, >=, <=), the result of comparing anything with a value that means you don't know, is you still don't know. And when this must then be treated as a full boolean result, it's seen as falsy.


When I build @summary, I convert all values to string.

It's likely because of #2 above, one of the conditional expressions is not operating as expected, and so the value is NOT converted to a string as you expected, and then because of #1 the problem propagates to entire value.
In short: the value of the @summary variable will end up as NULL, which is not allowed for that place in the History table.

@DaleK Rephrased to be more relevant.
